# Powershell 5.1 - Prompt for credentials

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.1

Question: How do I get a prompt to pop up asking for credentials when working with AD in the below script?

I have tried creating another powershell script that gathers the credentials to run this one, but it fails to start the script after entering the credentials.  I also tried to insert the credentials into the [ADSI] shortcut but wasn't able to figure that out.

My code as it is:

```
While($true){
Clear-Host
    $IPSet = Ping-IPRange -StartAddress 56.192.87.200 -EndAddress 56.192.87.254 -Interval 60
    $IPSet | Select-object IPAddress | foreach {
        $IPA = $_.IPAddress
        $HN = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($IPA) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hostname
        $Administrators = invoke-command -computername "$HN" {get-localgroupmember -Name "administrators"}
    if ($Administrators -like '*Admin*')
        {
            Write-Host 'Admin is already an administrator'
        }
    elseif ($Administrators -notlike '*Admin*')
        {
            $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$IPA/Administrators,group"
            $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://USA/EAGANACE,user"
            $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
            Write-Host 'Admin has been added as an administrator'
        }
}
}
```

What I have tried so far:

Creating a script to call this one with elevated credentials:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$ScriptLocation = "filepath"
Start-Process -Credential $Cred -FilePath "Powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-file $Scriptlocation"
```

I also tried -Credential on the [ADSI] command, but it does not take that.
I read that you can add credentials to [ADSI] but was unable to figure out how to do so.

Any criticism/guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to go about what I wanted done, seems easy and appears to be repeatable for any script you want to run.  The file paths don't really matter, but just for explanation/simplicity purposes I will use C:\Scripts as my example filepath and within that folder lies my script MyScript.ps1.

I created a shortcut of MyScript.ps1 in that same folder, then modified the properties of the shortcut as follows:

Go to 'Advanced...' check the box in front of 'Run as administrator' and hit ok

Target:
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe & 'C:\Scripts\MyScript.ps1'

Start in:
"C:\Scripts\MyScript.ps1"

Just replace the C:\Scripts\MyScript.ps1 with your path and keep the quotations in both the target and the start in location.  Finalize your changes by clicking ok on the properties page and then double click the shortcut for it to prompt you for administrator credentials and start your script once authorized.

If it isn't working make sure you have no spelling errors and you have the quotations in the right spot.  As long as you leave the myscript.ps1 in the same location you can move the shortcut around wherever you like and it will still call the myscript.ps1 as long as it lives in that Target: location.

Edit:
There are spaces between Powershell.exe, the &, and 'C:\Scripts\MyScripts.ps1'.  Best to just copy and paste it and replace the C:\Scripts\Myscripts.ps1 portion if you are having trouble.  Remember to keep the quotation marks!